# 1.9 admin panel login problem

Tags: admin, admin-panel

**Hi There,
Unfortunately I change my admin panel url from backend, after that my backend  panel is lost =)
I try change back my admin url from phpmyadmin:**

Fire up phpMyAdmin and open your core_config_data table. You have four or more rows to edit.

Find admin/url/custom and set to 0

The next three will have been set from the funky Admin Base URL you set in the Admin Config panel. You know what it is, the following rows will have it in the value field. Note their config_ID numbers and write them down.

admin/url/custom and all instances of web/unsecure/base_url web/secure/base_url

Set these to be what your website unsecured base url should be. Example: http://yourwebsite.com/ and don't forget the folder followed by a slash if you installed there.

EDIT: Flush /var/cache and /var/session.

[image]
[image]
[image]
**does't work for me.
this one doesn't work to:**

Locate the file;

/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php

and find;

‘cache_dir’ => null,

which can be found around line 91.

and change it to;

‘cache_dir’ => ‘tmp/’,

**and this too:**

Enable Magento exception printing

If this doesn’t fix your issue or to get a more detailed report on your error, you can temporarily enable exception printing.

Go to;

errors/local.xml.sample

and rename local.xml.sample to local.xml

**But now I have error page on my admin panel:**

```
There has been an error processing your request
Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

Trace:
#0 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(777): Zend_Uri::factory('admin/')
#1 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(611): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#2 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/Mage.php(382): Mage_Core_Model_Store->getBaseUrl('skin', NULL)
#3 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(349): Mage::getBaseUrl('skin', NULL)
#4 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(503): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getSkinBaseUrl(Array)
#5 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(1035): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getSkinUrl('reset.css', Array)
#6 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml(32): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getSkinUrl('reset.css')
#7 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/bilginirm...')
#8 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#9 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#10 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#11 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#16 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php(82): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#17 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController->loginAction()
#18 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#19 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /home/bilginirmak/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}
```

**Please Help, What I can do?**

UPDATE:

I will show you my phpmyadmin panel

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have 2 unsecure/base_url and secure/base_url so it's look like this.

and actually I change back my admin panel url  from phpmyadmin and my local.txt file is like this:

[image]

What is wrong let me know, I have same admin panel error.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change your admin url the only thing you needed to do was going to your `local.xml` and putting the correct name in this node, inside `<![CDATA[]]>`:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

So, you should just undo all changes you did and put desired `frontName` for backend in `local.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the unsecure and secure Base_Url do not contain the Admin Panel path and should look something like this

[image]

So change them back to the original URLs you had.

Then flush all cache and sessions again and don't forget to flush your browser cache and cookies too (or try a different browser).

Then go to https://www.yourdomain.com/admin/ or http://www.yourdomain.com/admin/ if you don't use SSL and see if you can login again.